# AOE Scheduler on 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, schedule, ce-1.9.1.1, email-scheduler

I am having issues with AOE Scheduler on Magento 1.9.1.1. After scheduling tasks through the extension, it does not seem to executive them at all. However if I directly run the task using "Run Now", it will work. It confuses me because I have a cron job setup on the server to run every 15 minutes. Yet, whatever task I "Run Now" via the extension, it runs it right away, totally disregarding the cron job time frame I have set on the server.

The whole reason I installed the extension was because cron is using 85% to 100% of the CPU and isn't stopping. My host actually had to disable cron.php to get it to stop. I'm thinking it's a bug in 1.9.1.1 because I didn't change anything and this all started after upgrading to 1.9.1.1 from 1.9.1.0.

Since installing the extension, the cron job I have setup on the server will not run (even though it's set to run every 15 minutes) unless I manually execute it by going to my browser and typing it's path directly in the address bar. However, if I do that, I go back to the same issue with CPU usage and cron not stopping.

I like that AOE Scheduler will run jobs (like sending email) on it's own (possibly outside of cron.php), but is there any way to have the schedule actually follow through and work on the extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AOE Scheduler doesn't run jobs on its on. It is only a frontend to get a better overview what the magento cron job is doing.

When you click "Run now" the plugin is exactly doing this, run this task once, NOW.

In any other case, you have to run the magento cron.php/cron.sh to have your cron jobs run.

Comment: At least that narrows it down a little. Cron is still failing to execute every 15 minutes as how I've always had it scheduled on the server. And I guess it shows in AOE Scheduler because of all of the pending tasks that aren't running.